# SOQL Field returning null when it is not

Tags: soql, null

I have a custom field:
Show_DateTime__c which is a formula(Date/time)

When I run the following anonymous apex:

```
Coverage_Request__c covreq = [Select Show_DateTime__c, name from Coverage_Request__c where name = 'a0Cg0000007URCI'];

system.debug('Show name is ' + covreq.Name);
system.debug('show date time is ' + covreq.Show_DateTime__c);
```

I get the output:

```
|DEBUG|Show name is a0Cg0000007URCI
|DEBUG|show date time is null
```

but when I log into my sandbox and go to the actual record there is a show_DateTime value:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since the discussion to debug this issue has grown quite involved, I have [moved it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65445/discussion-on-question-by-hans-donkersloot-soql-field-returning-null-when-it-is).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume for a moment that Show_DateTime__c is a `DateTime` data type.

You will need to implicitly convert it to a string for debug purposes....

`system.debug(msg)` will automatically convert an object to a string using the type's built-in `toString()` method. The DateTime type does not have a `toString()` method.

You can use `String.valueOf(covreq.Show_DateTime__c)` to force the type conversion.

Comment: If I try and do covreq.Show_DateTime__c.format(); I get a null pointer exception, so it is actually null

Answer (score 0):

This will occur if the user running the anonymous apex does not have the necessary permissions to read the field. Check the field level security and make it either readable or editable for the affected user/profile.